# PowerPoint change ink color (or active pen) via VBA or C#

Tags: c#, .net, vba, powerpoint

After several hours of googling/searching/debugging I decided to ask.

How can you change active pen or just the color while inking in PowerPoint.

**Scenario:** Currently inking on my PPT with **green** pen and want to change it to **red**. Please note this isn't during slidehow but in the powerpoint editing mode.

What I need is to either

1. Change currently selected pen color
2. Change currently selected pen

[image]

[image]

Upon futher research I found a code which clicks on items on the ribbon based on ID but I'm yet to locate appropriate IDs/actions to click on the pens.

```cs
var app = new Application();
app.Visible = MsoTriState.msoTrue;
var ppt = app.Presentations.Open( @"test.pptx" );

var control = app.CommandBars.FindControl(
    MsoControlType.msoControlButton,
    120 // ID
);

control.Execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but since inking was developed primarily for annotations during a slide show, the VBA object model places **.PointerColor** under the **.SlideShowSettings** object. This code can be used to change the color during a show:

```
Sub RedInk()
    ActivePresentation.SlideShowSettings.Run.View.PointerColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End Sub
```

This code will set the pointer color, but it won't be visible until you start a show:

```
Sub RedInkPreset()
    ActivePresentation.SlideShowSettings.PointerColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End Sub
```

There's nothing in the current object model in any programming language that will do what you want until Microsoft adds it to an object available in edit mode, like **ActivePresentation.Slides**.

Comment: I updated my original question as after a further research I found that you can control ribbon via FindControl with Execute methods. It's step closer to do what I need, hopefully there is a way to locate pen IDs.

Comment: Maybe. The Draw tab is new, and new features can take years to be added to the VBA object model. The last resort is always SendKeys, but the Draw tab doesn't seem to have any keyboard shortcuts assigned to it yet. What's the problem with just using the program interface to set the color?

Comment: Efficiency mostly. I use drawing tablet to draw on PPT slides and animate strokes with 'replay' animation. Drawing tablet has multiple physical keys that I wanted to assign different pen colors so I can quickly swap around when drawing (especially because automatinc stroke grouping is wonky at times). Right now I use autohotkey with shortcut combo ALT+J+I+G+LEFT(X times)+RIGHT (Y times)+Enter to select proper pen but it's not always working even with a slight delay so I wanted to make something more low level using interop.

Comment: If you add a command to the Quick Access Toolbar, it automatically get a numeric keyboard shortcut based on the icon position. So if you use File>Options>Quick Access Toolbar, and change the _Choose commands from_ dropdown to _All Commands, you can add Drawing Tools. If it's the fifth icon in the QAT, Alt + 5 will run it, giving slightly faster access to the pen choice.

Answer (score 0):

On 365 version, I could manage to pick the {x}th pen and change the color, using VBA 'Sendkeys' method. You know, PowerPoint has now limited the number of available pens to only 3.

```
Sub PickPen()
    '//Pen index is 'Arrow selector, Lasso, Eraser, 1st pen, 2nd pen, 3rd pen....'
    
    PickPenIndex 3      '// the 1st pen
    SendKeys "{ENTER}"  '// Chosen
    
End Sub

Function PickPenIndex(penIdx As Integer)

    SendKeys "{ESC}"    '//first of all, escape the pen mode
    SendKeys "%jg"      '//go to 'Draw' menu(Alt+j) and 'Drawing tool' group('g' key) again(the arrow tool is selected automatically)
    DoEvents
    SendKeys "{RIGHT " & penIdx & "}"    '// move to the pen
    
End Function

Sub PenColor13()
    
    PenColorIndex 1, 3 'change the 1st pen color to the color in (1,3)
    
End Sub
Sub PenColor24()
    
    PenColorIndex 2, 4 'change the 1st pen color to the color in (2,4)
    
End Sub
Sub PenColor32()
    
    PenColorIndex 3, 2 'change the 1st pen color to the color in (3,2)
    
End Sub
Function PenColorIndex(rowIdx As Integer, colIdx As Integer)
    
    PickPenIndex 3      '// select the 1st pen
    DoEvents
    
    SendKeys "%{DOWN}"  '// Pen properties
    DoEvents
 
    SendKeys "{TAB}"
    SendKeys "{DOWN}"
    DoEvents
    
    If rowIdx > 1 Then SendKeys "{DOWN " & rowIdx - 1 & "}"
    DoEvents
    
    If colIdx > 1 Then SendKeys "{RIGHT " & colIdx - 1 & "}"
    DoEvents
    
    SendKeys "{ENTER}"
    
End Function
```

Here I could only pick a color that is already on the color list. I tried to open the pen color dialog but failed to enter a user color in Hex code. I think the window focus was lost when the color dialog was open.

If you use AutoHotey, you might be able to open the pen color dialog (Alt+'m') and then go to the 'User Color' Tab and finally enter a HEX color value you want.